# Prevent empty line in ejs if statement

Tags: ejs

In if statement of ejs, it produces an unexpected empty line.
The following is my ejs code block for test:

```
test block
<% if(false) { %>
    line should be hidden
<% } %>
test block
```

Rendered output:

```
test block

test block
```

There is an empty line between the "test block". How to prevent it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to prevent it:

```
test block
<% if(false) { %>
    line should be hidden
<% } _%>
test block
```